# Unit Test Angular http.post with Data in Header

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-http

I am trying to write a unit test for service that performs a http.post to an api that passes credentials in the header.

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http, signInService) {

    $scope.LogIn = function(usrnm, pwd) {
        signInService.authUser(usrnm, pwd)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // Display success message
            $scope.gotToAddress = data.successUrl;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           // Display error message
        }
    }
});
```

**signInService:**

```
app.service('signInService', function($http) {

    this.authUser = function (usrnm, pwd) {

        return $http({
            url: '/api/json/authenticate',
            method: "POST",
            data: '{}',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-app-Username': usrnm,
                'X-app-Password': pwd
            }
        });
    };
});
```

**Unit test:**

```
describe('mocking service http call', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var LoginController, $scope;

    describe('with httpBackend', function() {
        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend) {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();

            $httpBackend.when('POST', '/api/json/authenticate', {}, function(headers) {
            return {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-app-Username': 'admin',
                'X-app-Password': 'admin'
            };
        }).respond(200)

            LoginController = $controller('LoginController', { $scope: $scope });
            $httpBackend.flush();
        }));

        it('should set data to "things and stuff"', function() {
            expect($scope.data).toEqual({things: 'and stuff'});
        });
    });
});
```

When running the test i am seeing the following error: mocking service http call » with httpBackend
Error: No pending request to flush !

---

Controller with service on .succeed:

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http, signInService, cookieSrv) {

    $scope.LogIn = function(usrnm, pwd) {
        signInService.authUser(usrnm, pwd)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // Display success message
            var cookieID = 'myCookie';
            cookieSrv.createCookie(cookieID, data.token, 3, data.redirectUrl);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           // Display error message
        }
    }
});
```

**cookieSrv.js**

```
app.service('cookieSrv', function() {
    return {
        createCookie : function(cookieID, token, days, redirectUrl) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
            else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = cookieID+"="+token+expires+"; path=/";

            window.location.assign(redirectUrl)
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller defines a method logIn on the `$scope` but you do not call this function in the test, and hence actual http request is not made.

Modify the test by calling `$scope.logIn` before you call `flush`

```
LoginController = $controller('LoginController', { $scope: $scope });
$scope.logIn("Test","test");  // Add this
$httpBackend.flush();
```

Comment: added your recommendation and get the following on running the test: System output:
Firefox 37.0.0 ERROR Some of your tests did a full page reload!

Comment: Maybe something in your controller code is doing this. I see you set variable such as $scope.gotToAddress

Comment: i think it was becuase in my original question i did not include a cookie service which i am calling on .success of the post, please see my updated question.

Comment: WHy are you using window.location? The first rule of unit testing is to mock all dependencies. You should mock the cookieSrv altogether. Also use $location service.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, appreciated. How do i mock the cookieSrv too?

Comment: You can create a mock object of cookieSrv yourself or use jasmine syy